# XSLT converting linear structure to non-linear

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I've and XML

```
<main>
    <div type='scene'>
        <l>l1</l>
        <sp>A speach</sp>
        <l>l2</l>
        <pb />
        <l>l3</l>
       <l>14</l>
    </div>
</main>
```

My task is to convert this to

```
<div class="line-group">
    <l>l1</l>
    <div class="speach">
       A speach
    </div>
    <l>l2</l>
</div>
<div class="line-group">
    <l>l3</l>
    <l>l4</l>
</div>
```

I understand that there may be arbitrary number of `<pb />` and this output can only be achived properly if there is no consecutive `<pb />` and there is no `<pb />` at the begining and at the end.

However we can have this approach to replace all `<pb />` with `</div><div class="line-group">` and have a `<div class="line-group">` at the begining and have a `</div>` at end.

How can I do this in XSLT ?

I've templates for all other tags, I've used sp in the example to show `<l>` is not the only child item.

Comment: What version of XSLT, and can you provide a well-formed input and output sample (with a single root-level element)?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: using XSLT 1.0. It is actually a big TEI document. I'll try to minimize it using some fake tags. here pb means page break. and I am trying to make each page one slide in HTML and then control with javascript

Answer (score 2):

You can define a *key* to gather the non-`pb` elements in each scene into groups based on their nearest preceding `pb` element.

```
<xsl:key name="elByPb" match="*[not(self::pb)]"
                       use="concat(generate-id(..), '|',
                                   generate-id(preceding-sibling::pb[1]))" />
```

Now to process a scene you create a `line-group` for the elements before the first `pb` and then another one from those following each `pb`:

```
<xsl:template match="div[@type='scene']">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
    <xsl:call-template name="line-group">
      <xsl:with-param name="groupKey" select="concat(generate-id(), '|')" />
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="pb" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="pb" name="line-group">
  <xsl:param name="groupKey"
             select="concat(generate-id(..), '|', generate-id())" />
  <div class="line-group">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('elByPb', $groupKey)" />
  </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Here I'm taking advantage of the fact that the `generate-id` of an empty node set is (by definition) the empty string, so the elements before the first `pb` in a section will be keyed on `"id-of-parent|"`

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="div">
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-ending-with="pb">
<div class="line-group">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
 </div>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="pb"></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="l">

     <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
     </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Exactly what I thought initially, but the OP says they need XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

disable-output-escape='yes" can be used, but it is not an elegant method.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="div">
<root>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;div class=&quot;line-group&quot;></xsl:text>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/div></xsl:text>  
</root>
</xsl:template> 

<xsl:template match="pb">
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;/div></xsl:text>  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;div class=&quot;line-group&quot;></xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="l">
     <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
     </xsl:copy>   
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

At a first approximation, I think you have two options.

1. You can apply templates to each pb element, and in the template for a given pb you can generate the div you want, with the attributes you want, and then walk the tree in depth-first order to process the nodes between that pb and the next.  It would surprise me if you were able to make much use of any templates in a conventional stylesheet for the input vocabulary, since probably none of them will be written in a way that is sensitive to the possible occurrence of one or more pb elements in the middle of the element being processed.

   The proper handling of pb elements occurring in text will pose some challenges.  Consider this bit from Hamlet:

   ```
   <div type="scene" n="III.ii">
     ...
     <sp><speaker>King.</speaker>
       <p>What do you call the play?</p>
     </sp>
     <sp><speaker>Hamlet.</speaker>
       <p><title>The Mousetrap</title>.  Marry, how? 
       <seg xml:id="III.ii.243">Tropically</seg>.
       This play is the image of a murder done
       in Vienna:  Gonzago is the Duke's name;
       his wife, Baptista.  You shall see anon.
       'Tis a knavish piece of work, but what of
       that?  Your Majesty, and we that have 
       <seg xml:id="III.ii.247">free</seg>
       <pb n="107"/>
       souls, it touches us not.  Let the 
       <seg xml:id="III.ii.248">galled jade 
       winch</seg>; our withers are unwrung
       </p>
     </sp>
     ...
   </div>
   ```

   (I have omitted the notes, but left the seg elements which mark the text they attach to.)  What should the beginning of the div for page 107 look like?  Does it start with PCDATA?

   ```
   <div n="pb107">
   souls, it touches us not.
   ```

   Or does the enclosing p element need to be split, so page 107 begins

   ```
   <div n="pb107">
   <p part="F">souls, it touches us not.
   ```

   It's not clear from your question whether your output is supposed to be a new document in the TEI vocabulary, with a different structure (in which case the class attribute is unexpected) or HTML (in which case the l element is unexpected); since TEI divs do not take text nodes as children, the first option is unavailable if you are writing a TEI-to-TEI transform.
2. You can adapt the extremely clever approach outlined by Ian Roberts.  It will need to be generalized a bit, in two ways.

   First, the key will almost certainly need to be based not on the most recent sibling pb (`preceding-sibling::pb[1]`) but on the most recent pb at any depth (`preceding::pb[1]`).

   And second, you'll need to remove the assumption that an element that begins between two pb elements will also end between the two pb elements.  That is, you must be prepared for one pb to occur between two speeches in a scene, and the next to occur within a speech.  In the fragment quoted above, Hamlet's speech begins after `<pb n="106"/>`, but it must not all appear in the div for page 106:  the end of it (beginning with "souls") must appear in the div for page 107.  One way to handle this might be to pass the pb element in question (or its generated ID) as a parameter, each time you call apply-templates.  And then, in each template, test whether the pb passed in as a parameter is the same as `./preceding::pb[1]`.  If so, continue; if not, do nothing.

I won't attempt a full solution, since your requirements aren't clear enough to me.  Good luck!